# Adding a Check in - Out indicator in sql select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to create a select query that will look at a list of employees and determine if they are in or out. the table will have the following data:

employeeid,date/time

I need to find any employee that has more then 1 record and then toggle a new column to identify if the employee is checked in or out based on the date/time.

Ex.

```
999, 2016-01-01: 9:00     -- This would have a column with 1 added
999, 2016-01-01: 15:00    -- This would have a column with 2 added
999, 2016-01-01: 18:00    -- This would go back to 1
```

I need this to look at all the lines in the table. Is this possible. I do not have access to make any changes to the original table.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? rowno modulo 2?

Comment: You could try and select the even or odd number of the visit count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it should work

```
    SELECT employeeid,Cast (date/time as date),
   (RANK() OVER   
   (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY date/time)) as 'in/out'
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY employeeid,Cast (date/time as date)
```

Comment: I am using mssql 2012.

Comment: I need to do this for all the rows. If the employee has 3 rows then I need to see the 3 lines not just the last one. The max above will now provide all the rows correct?

Comment: check it I changed according to your logic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check on odd or even numbers?

```
SELECT
 Employee_id,
 Date,
 IF(COUNT(*) % 2 = 0, 1, 2) AS 'Lastvisit'
FROM 
 table
```

Comment: That's invalid (standard) SQL.

Comment: What is standard SQL?

Comment: There is no `IF` in the SQL standard and single quotes are for character constants, not for identifiers (so `as 'Lastvisit'` should be `as "Lastvisit"`). Also the `%` operator is non-standard.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. Where can I find documentation about the standard SQL? Can I use this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL as my basis next time I answer a question which has no specific engine written?

Comment: Thanks Ritesh!  This really helps. It is exactly what I was looking for.